# Converting Node to Int []

Tags: java, arrays, pacman

I am new to java programming, and currently working on a pacman Ai controller. We were given base code, with a method `List(Node) getPillNodes`, which returns all the node indices with pills. So what I am trying to do is tell pacman to go after the nodes that have pills, however my only idea was to do this:

```
int[] pills=game.getPillNodes();
int[] powerPills=game.getPowerPillIndices();        

ArrayList<Integer> targets=new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i=0;i<pills.length;i++) //check which pills are available           
if(game.checkPill(i))
targets.add(pills[i]); etc...
```

How would I go about turning that `List` into an an `int []` so I can use the code I have written above. Please ask any clarifying questions needed. I apologize if I missed something. Thanks in Advance!!

Here is the Node Class

```
int getX();
int getY();

boolean isPill();
boolean isPowerPill();
boolean isJunction();

int getNumNeighbors();
Node getNeighbor(int inDirection);
List<Node> getNeighbors();
int getPathDistance(Node to);

static int getReverse(int direction)
{
    switch(direction)
    {
        case 0: return 2;
        case 1: return 3;
        case 2: return 0;
        case 3: return 1;
    }
    return 4;
}
```

}

Here is the Maze Class:

String getName();                    // Returns name of maze

```
Node getInitialAttackerPosition();   // Returns the starting position of the hero
Node getInitialDefendersPosition();  // Returns the starting position of the defenders (i.e., first node AFTER leaving the lair)
Node getNode(int x, int y);          // Get Node from X,Y position

int getNumberPills();                // Total number of pills in the maze
int getNumberPowerPills();           // Total number of power pills in the maze
int getNumberOfNodes();              // Total number of nodes in the graph (i.e., those with pills, power pills and those that are empty)

List<Node> getPillNodes();           // Returns the indices to all the nodes that have pills
List<Node> getPowerPillNodes();      // Returns all the nodes that have power pills
List<Node> getJunctionNodes();       // Returns the indices to all the nodes that are junctions
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to convert to an `int[]` and not just use the `Node`'s directly?

Comment: I am just unfamiliar with Nodes as was trying to do it in a way I knew. Would you be able to explain a simple way to apply what I was trying to do by using the Node's directly?

Comment: What does the `Node` class look like? Does it contain one `int` or more?

Comment: Posted Node class code above to make it easier to read. The method that I was trying to use is located in the Maze class which I have also posted above too try to make things make sense

Comment: Well I'm assuming in your `checkPill()` method you want to check both the `y` and `x` position of the `Node`, so you can pass a `Node` to the function and then call the `getX` and `getY` methods to get the ints